# Hibernate - Can't delete child if parent has cascade set

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I try to delete an entity which is a child of another entity (`one-to-many`).

The problem is:
 If the parent has set a cascade type, I am not able to delete a child directly. The delete command is ignored (using `JpaRepository`). Only if I remove the cascade setting I am able to delete child.
Is there a way to do this without a native SQL statement?

Parent Entity:

```
@Entity
public class ExplorerItem {
...
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "explorerItem")
   private Set<UserACL> userAcls = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

Child Entity:

```
@Entity
public class UserACL {
...
   @ManyToOne
   private ExplorerItem explorerItem;
...
}
```

I'm using `JpaRepositories` created by Spring Boot:

```
public interface UserACLRepository extends JpaRepository<UserACL, Long> {
    void deleteByUser(User user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `orphanRemoval="true"` in your `@OneToMany` annotation. Setting orphanRemoval to true automatically removes disconnected references of entities. On the other hand, if we specify only `CascadeType.Remove`, no action is taken as it will only disconnect from the association, which is not equivalent of deleting an object.

Eg.

```
@Entity
public class ExplorerItem {
...
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval="true", mappedBy = "explorerItem")
   private Set<UserACL> userAcls = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```