# JPA delete method dosen't work properly even if i used cascade All

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, rest

I can delete from parent to child but cannot delete from child to parent even I have used *cascade All*
in simple words, if I delete a category the quizzes automatically delete but when I try to delete a quiz by its id the delete does not work.

**Parent class**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class CategoryDomain {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int categoryId;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<QuizDomain> quizDomains = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

**Child class**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class QuizDomain {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int quizId;
    private Boolean activeStatus;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String maxMarks;
    private String numberOfQuestions;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private CategoryDomain category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quizDomain" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<QuestionDomain> questionDomains = new HashSet<>();
    
}
```

Comment: What is exactly that you are trying to achieve? Are you deleting the `QuizDomain` by its ID and it does not work, or are you removing it from the `quizDomains` set in `CategoryDomain`?

Comment: Deleting from child to parent doesn't make sense. What is the goal here? Do you want to delete the `CategoryDomain` when you delete a `QuizDomain`? That will result in you deleting not just one `QuizDomain`, but all of the ones in that category.

Comment: I wanted to delete a quiz individually but the delete operation doesn't work but if I delete a category the delete operation works fine and automatically deletes the quiz when a category is deleted. My question is why I cannot delete a quiz individually?

Comment: My question is quite related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745790/hibernate-cant-delete-child-if-parent-has-cascade-set

Comment: i have used Used orphanRemoval = true in Parent class like but that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try using cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE

Delete all children automatically when parent delete

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

Delete child automatically from children list when it is deleted

```
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

Even if it is one2one mapping:

```
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```